# How to give a custom name to a Dto model in api-platform?

Tags: dto, api-platform.com

When I use a Dto in the models of the api documentation, the name of the Dto is documented as follows, Customer: 01d691680190c1b19dfee75af0f2e292, it is possible to customize this name to Customer: Input or anything else.

This is the configuration of my resource:

```
App\Entity\Customer\Customer:
collectionOperations:
    register:
        method: POST
        path: /register
        controller: App\Controller\ShopApi\Customer\RegisterCustomerAction
        input:
            class: App\Dto\RegisterCustomerRequest
            name: RegisterCustomerRequest
itemOperations:
    get:
        normalization_context:
            jsonld_embed_context: true
            groups: ['customer:read']
            swagger_definition_name: CustomerResponse
```

But then in the api doc I get as a model:

```
Customer:01d691680190c1b19dfee75af0f2e292 {
email*  string
plainPassword*  string
firstName*  string
lastName*   string
gender* string
identificationNumber*   string
typeIdentificationNumber*   string
subscribedToNewsletter  boolean
confirmTermsConditions  boolean
addressAlias    string
address*    string
countryCode*    string
provinceCode    string
provinceName    string
city*   string
postcode*   string
phoneNumber*    string  }
```

Comment: Juan, have you managed to solve the issue?

Comment: No the problem continues

Comment: Does the problem still continue to this day?

Comment: I do not know I have not updated my project, but here is the response I received in an issue I did on github, there is a reply that a PR has been made, where the name is clearer but not customizable.

Comment: This is link of the issue https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/issues/1225